# The <a> download attribute in html5 doesn't work at all in any web browser

Tags: php, html

** My Code Snippet

```html
<button ><a href="Palak_Lohia_Resume.pdf" download class="button4"> </a></button>

It just opens the pdf file in other tab but doesn't force the download.
```

Comment: Which one of browsers are you running this HTML?

Comment: Tried in Google Chrome, Firefox and edge.

Comment: And are you sure Palak_Lohia_Resume.pdf file exists? Because it seems that file does'nt exists and probably thats why your download link is not working

Comment: It does exist. As mentioned above it also opens my pdf file in a new tab but doesn't force the download process

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

The **download** tag is HTML5 attribute, so it is very important to have the HTML document structured correctly, the place where you place it is not relevant, only that the code is structured under the HTML5 standard. Here is an example of the correct way to use it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" xml:lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- your code -->
<button><a href="file.pdf" download class="button4"></a></button>

<!-- correct form -->
<a href="file.pdf" download class="button4"><button>Download PDF</button></a>

<!-- other form -->
<a href="file.pdf" download class="button4">Download PDF</a>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem really is that you placed the **button** element outside the **a** tag.

Answer (score -1):

i have been trying this to with a button to download a file only i tried it with `.mp3` `.wav` `.ogg` files but that shouldn't be any different.

after a while of changing codes i stopped changing my code as it just kept on doing the same thing. the only thing i had to do now was putting my `.mp3` file into an `.zip` folder and tell that button to download the `.zip` folder with the audio file in it:

```
<button>
    <a href="HooniganProds\songs.zip" download>Click to Download!</a>
    </button>
```

i hope this will help you on with your problem.